# Como fazer uma classe para manipular Graphics2D no paint?

Tags: java, graphics

No código a seguir eu tentei criar uma classe Sprite para manipular os desenhos, a função dele seria transformar as sprites em Graphics2D e usa-lo no paint. Mas a unica forma que encontrei para liga-los foi fazendo esse:

```
public Sprite(Graphics g) {
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
}
```

O problema é que no código do Title, quando o load = true ocorre, ele não passa pela inicialização do objeto Sprite, o drawImage não funciona, então no primeiro paint ele faz tudo certinho, no segundo paint com o load = true, tudo some e o draw não funciona. Alguma idéia de como corrigir isso?

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import engine.Display;
import engine.Sprite;

public class Title extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    // IMAGENS

    Sprite city1;
    Sprite city2;
    Sprite tipo;

    private int phase = 1;
    private boolean load = false;

    public Title(Display window){

        setSize( 800, 600 );
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
        t.start();
        window.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (load == false) {

            city1 = new Sprite(g);
            city2 = new Sprite(g);
            tipo = new Sprite(g);

            city1.setImage("images/scene/logo2.png");
            city2.setImage("images/scene/logo2.png");
            tipo.setImage("images/scene/tipo.png");

            city1.setLocation((800/2) - (city1.getWidth()/2), 150 + (tipo.getHeight()/2));
            city2.setLocation((800/2) - (city2.getWidth()/2), 150 + (tipo.getHeight()/2));
            tipo.setLocation ((800/2) - (city2.getWidth()/2), 150);

            city1.setHeight(0);
            city2.setHeight(0);

            city1.setAnimation(true);
            city2.setAnimation(true);

            city1.setMotionAnimation(0, 0, 0, -1, 0);
            city2.setMotionAnimation(0, 0, 0, +1, 0);

            city1.draw();
            city2.draw();  
            tipo.draw();

            load = true;

        }

        city1.draw();
        city2.draw();  
        tipo.draw();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (phase == 1){
            repaint();  
        } 
    }
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Sprite {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private String string;
    private boolean visibility;
    private float alpha = 1f;
    private Font font;
    private Graphics2D g2d;

    private boolean animation = false;
    private int spd_x = 0;
    private int spd_y = 0;
    private int spd_width = 0;
    private int spd_height = 0;
    private float spd_alpha = 0;

    public Sprite(Graphics g) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    }

    public void setImage(String path){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Arquivo (" + path + ") não encontrado!");
        }

        this.setHeight(image.getHeight());
        this.setWidth(image.getWidth());
    }

    public void setString(String string, Font font, float alpha){
        this.font = font;
        this.alpha = alpha;
        this.string = string;
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setFont(font);
    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setDimension(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setMotionAnimation(int spd_x, int spd_y, int spd_width, int spd_height, float spd_alpha){
        this.spd_x = spd_x;
        this.spd_y = spd_y;
        this.spd_width = spd_width;
        this.spd_height = spd_height;
        this.spd_alpha = spd_alpha;
    }

    public void setAnimation (boolean animation){
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (image != null){
            if (animation == true) {
                this.x += this.spd_x;
                this.y += this.spd_y;
                this.width += this.spd_width;
                this.height += this.spd_height;
                this.alpha += this.spd_alpha;
            }
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
        } else if (string != null){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            g2d.drawString(string, x, y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema fazendo com que o comando draw() receba o graphics g e após isso fiz novamente a variavel g2d, igual fiz na iniciação do Sprite.

```
public void draw(Graphics g)
g2d = (Graphics2D) g
```

Mas se houver alguma dica para fazer essa classe corretamente, aceito.

Comment: Não faz sentido algum passar graphics no construtor, sendo que você só precisa dele para desenhar no método draw. Essa é a forma correta, remova ele do construtor e deixe o construtor apenas para definir propriedades do objeto e deixe apenas neste método draw.